# Where do I find the scripts of my wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, content-management-system

Usually on a website the scripts are in the footer and when I view the source code of my wordpress blog I can see all the scripts on the bottom of the page. What I am looking for is the php page in my theme folder, where I can find all scripts (I do not mean the script files, I mean the page, where they

Comment: It obviously depends on how the theme is structured.

Try to globally search for: `wp_enqueue_scripts` in your theme folder and you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such page in Wordpress, because not only theme includes scripts. Some scripts included by Wordpress core, some by plugins and theme.

You can use action wp_enqueue_scripts to get list of all scripts included:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts